# Weird sprinkles

Tags: particles

Every time I try to make the sprinkles as a particle. the appear in a big spherelike thing instead of spreading out on the Icing. What is the source of the problem, and/or how can I solve it?[image: This is how it looks, please help]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It seems like the particles are generated in a very small space on the icing. But to investigate that further you should add the file as @moonboots suggested.

Comment: The file is too big to share there, any ideas about how I can share it with you?

Comment: How big is too big? I just tried 3.5 GB, the upload only says it might take some time... Can you just put the particle emitter and maybe particle objects in a separate file?

Comment: You will learn more if you watch to the video again try to figure out what you did differently.

Comment: I did it lots of times, and I checked every setting I saw, but it all is the same.

Comment: It just sais that files that are bigger than 30Mb can't be uploaded